# Hide Cells Based on Dropdown, Keeps activating when not selected

Tags: vba, excel

I created my VBA Object to hide and activate cells based on if the particular value was selected. This i all contained within the first column.

However, whenever I then continue to edit any other column once I input information it hides everything on me.

The full codes is below. It's mainly the same thing repeated 5 times over. Thanks!

```html
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 3 And Target.Value = "Cashback" Then
        Application.Rows("4:7").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Application.Rows("4:7").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    
        If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 3 And Target.Value = "Content" Then
        Application.Rows("8:25").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Application.Rows("8:25").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 3 And Target.Value = "Price Comparison" Then
        Application.Rows("26:40").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Application.Rows("26:40").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 3 And Target.Value = "Technology" Then
        Application.Rows("41:52").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Application.Rows("41:52").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    
        If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 3 And Target.Value = "Vouchers" Then
        Application.Rows("53:79").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Application.Rows("53:79").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    
            If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 3 And Target.Value = "All" Then
        Application.Rows("3:200").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    
    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored the code a bit to make it more efficient, easy to understand / maintain, and, most importantly, to meet the requirement.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A3")) Is Nothing and Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Me.Rows("4:200").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Select Case Target.Value

        Case Is = "Cashback": Me.Rows("4:7").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "Content": Me.Rows("8:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "Price Comparison": Me.Rows("26:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False

        '... Continue with rest of scenarios ...

        Case Is = "All": Me.Rows("4:200").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    End Select

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: This cleared up what I was looking for and is a much more sensible use of the code I was trying to implement. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 3 Then
        If Target.Value = "Cashback" Then
            Rows("4:7").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Application.Rows("4:7").Select
            Rows("4:7").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

        If Target.Value = "Content" Then
            Rows("8:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Rows("8:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

        If Target.Value = "Price Comparison" Then
            Rows("26:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Rows("26:40").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

        If Target.Value = "Technology" Then
            Rows("41:52").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Rows("41:52").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

        If Target.Value = "Vouchers" Then
            Rows("53:79").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Rows("53:79").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

        If Target.Value = "All" Then
            Rows("3:200").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `Else` of the `Select` statement. Try this code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 14 Apr 2017

    Dim Rng As Range

    With Target
        If .Address = Cells(3, 1).Address Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Set Rng = Range.Rows("3:200")
            If .Value <> "All" Then
                Rng.Hidden = True
                Select Case .Value
                    Case "Cashback"
                        Set Rng = Rows("4:7")
                    Case "Content"
                        Set Rng = Rows("8:25")
                    Case "Price Comparison"
                        Set Rng = Rows("26:40")
                    Case "Technology"
                        Set Rng = Rows("41:52")
                    Case "Vouchers"
                        Set Rng = Rows("53:79")
                End Select
            End If
            Rng.Hidden = False
            Rng.Select
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```